# How to get center points of an images with different resolution

Tags: image-processing, image, cluster-analysis

I have an images of particles and I want to get the center point coordinates for each particle. I can get the coordinates with other imaging tools, but since my calculations are in mathematica i want to do everything in the same notebook. here are two images, one is with more resolution than the other one, preferably I want the image with Low Resolution

High Resolution [image: HighRes]   Low Resolution[image: Low Res]
Expecting [image: Expecting]

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

I followed the example in the article 
[How to Count Cells, Annihilate Sailboats, and Warp the Mona Lisa](https://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) on the Wolfram Blog, and got a pretty good result on the high resolution image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Sed.png"];
binary = Binarize[ImageAdjust[img], 0.4];
dist = ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform[binary, 0.5];
markers = MaxDetect[dist, 0.1];
HighlightImage[
 img,
 {Red, Values@ComponentMeasurements[markers, "Centroid"]}
 ]
```

[image: Output of code]

I hope it might help. Perhaps someone else can refine it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get an error , I think my mathematica 9, doesn't recognize `Values`, what is the alternative? here is the error code:
HighlightImage::mkinv: Expecting either an image or graphics with dimensions {162,449} or a list of positions to specify markers instead of {RGBColor[1,0,0],Values[{1->{64.,448.167},2->{99.,448.},3->{80.6111,440.722},4->{111.,437.},5->{60.5,431.583},<<41>>,47->{94.5,309.167},48->{73.9615,305.5},49->{122.75,299.5},50->{59.8,296.7},<<86>>}]}. >>

Comment: @RacaioCmoto it is always better to include the version of your Mathematica/WL, especially when it is not the most updated one. As to fix your problem, one can make an intuitive jump that since `Values` pulls out the values of each `Rule` or `Association` and lists them, and each key is the indexed position in the list of values (more or less),  one might consider the following: `Range@Length@#/.#&@ComponentMeasures[markers, “Centroid”]`. Maybe there’s a simpler way, though.

Comment: I would use `cm[[All, 2]]` where `cm` is `ComponentMeasurements[...]`.